# Android App priority for a sensor

Tags: event-listener, android, proximitysensor

I'm not English so excuse me if I'll do some language mistake.. My question is: if two different apps request at the same time the control of a sensor (with a EventListener,) such as the proximity sensor, which one have the priority to control that sensor?

I try to be more more specific.. I would like to create an app that always control the proximity sensor and when it's covered do an action. Now the problem: some application , also some pre-installed app as some Samsung app, when opened control the proximity sensor to do something when it's covered, just like my app: what app have the priority when the proximity sensor is covered?

Comment: sounds like you have a race condition there and there is nothing like priority to solve it. All apps have the same level of priority so who ever get's there first is the owner

Comment: No system or user app have elevated control over another with regard to sensors. Android works by first-in-first-serve principle, so apps are queued for execution based on their ordering.